# Private schedules of Donald Trump: What does "RON" in diary stand for?

Tags: united-states, president, donald-trump, bureaucracy

Recently the [private schedules](https://www.axios.com/read-trumps-private-leaked-executive-time-schedules-00e9313a-3066-4988-a6dc-711a47de661e.html) of Donald Trump have been leaked.

In those files, at the end of each day there is some acronym `RON` placed. What does this stand for?

**Example:**

```
  1:30 PM          EXECUTIVE TIME
  (3hr, 30 min)    Location:        Oval Office

  RON:             The White House
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Apparently that's a common (in government/Washington DC, anyway) scheduling acronym which stands for "remain overnight."

> The globe-trotting secretary of state and globe-trotting former president each kept up frantic travel schedules, which meant they were often not in the same place at the same time — or even on the same continent. The calendars indicate where Hillary and Bill each spent the night: **"RON," in Washington parlance, the acronym for "remain overnight."**
>
> On weekdays, the Clintons typically spent the evenings in their separate homes — Hillary in northwest Washington near her office at the State Department, and Bill in Chappaqua near his office in New York. But the Clintons spent a lot of time traveling the world. On March 17, 2010, the entry read: HRC RON En route Moscow/ WJC RON White Oak, FL. Other exotic RONs: HRC RON London, England/WJC RON Stockholm Sweden. HRC RON Abu Dhabi, UAE/WJC RON London, England. HRC RON Taj Palace Hotel, New Delhi, WJC RON Chappaqua, NY.

[CNBC: What I learned reading 3721 Pages of Hillary Clinton's Schedule](https://www.cnbc.com/2016/08/30/what-i-learned-reading-3721-pages-of-hillary-clintons-schedule.html)